# Conditional update in custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-binding

I have a custom binding that is used to re-initialise a dom element whenever a field ("Type") is changed on the viewmodel. This is defined in an update callback.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Value, initValueField: Type()" />

ko.bindingHandlers.initValueField = {
    update:function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
};
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poztin/DMLzd/3/) for a stripped down demo.

As I understand it, one of the conditions for the update being invoked is the following:

[The mechanics of custom bindings](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html)

> Any time that another binding in the same data-bind attribute is
>   triggered. This helps ensure things like the value is appropriate when
>   the options are changed.

The issue I have is that this update callback is also called whenever the value on the viewmodel changes.

So...**is it possible to either:**

1. **Suppress one of the bindings from invoking the custom binding.**
2. **Detect the source of the invocation inside the custom binding.**

Comment: Why do you need a custom binding for this? Can't you just subscribe to the type observable and set the value of your field there? Another solution would be to override the value binding

Comment: My custom binding sets up the input field with a jQuery UI component based on the Type member. Whenever this Type member changes I may need to change the UI component (e.g. change from Datepicker to Autocomplete). I have this working, however the custom binding also fires whenever the Value member changes. If you think a custom binding isn't necessary, I'd be grateful if you could post the alternative.

Comment: In that case, a custom binding is a good solution. I just asked because it was not entirely clear what you were trying to achieve. I need to think about this a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found potential workarounds to the problem here:

[Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #3 - All Bindings Fire Together](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html)

The options are:

1. Split the bindings up by putting them onto separate elements (maybe a container element).
2. Similar to point 1, but use containerless bindings to separate them out.
3. Use a computed observable in the custom binding `init` to manage the updates manually.

Comment: Good find! I don't know if you knew that blog already, but it's a great resource!

Answer (score 0):

you can perhaps check for changes of the observable. And only then execute the action. Something like this:

```
(function () {
    var cache;
    ko.bindingHandlers.initValueField = {
        init:function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var currentValue = valueAccessor();
            cache = currentValue();
        },
        update:function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var currentValue = valueAccessor();
            if (cache !== currentValue()) {
                alert('Hello World');
                cache = currentValue();
            }
        }
    };
}());
```

The **cache** variable stores the old value of the observable. The **alert** is only done when the current value is different from this old one.

the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DMLzd/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element` argument in your custom binding to see the DOM element that invokes that binding. See http://jsfiddle.net/DMLzd/7/ for conditional within your custom binding which uses `id` attribute of textbox to decide whether to perform actions or not. I added additional textbox and button with different ID that invokes the custom binding.